# Unexpected data returned by PyMySQL when using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I generated SQL query for my database as following:

```sql
SELECT match_id, Group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'winners' 
FROM   players 
WHERE  match_id = 4 
       AND rank = 1 
GROUP  BY match_id;
```

(for structure and example data, see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21c485/3))

which results in MySQL:

```
+----------+------------+
| match_id | winners    |
+----------+------------+
|        4 | P106, P107 |
+----------+------------+
```

So I tried to apply this SQL query into python using `pymysql` module:

```py
conn = pymysql.connect(**DB_CONFIG, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """SELECT match_id, Group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'winners' 
         FROM   players 
         WHERE  match_id = %s
                AND rank = 1 
         GROUP  BY match_id """
cur.execute(sql, (4, ))
result = cur.fetchall()
```

But strangely, the value of result was:

```py
[{'match_id': 4, 'winners': 'P106'}]
```

So, why is the result of `pymysql` different from the result of MySQL Client? How can I fix it?

Comment: I believe you want a `value` separator rather than a `name` separator on your `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: `name` is just a column name, Isn't that syntax right?

Comment: Yes that is the correct syntax - do you have example rows of the `players` table?

Comment: @jwjhdev I added some example rows

Comment: thank you - I will try to reproduce

Comment: here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21c485/3) if you would like to add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I added into the question

Comment: Are you sure that the python code is executed on the same table/database?

Comment: @forpas Yes, of course it is

Comment: Well, I've solved the problem. I just re-opened my connection on IDLE and it worked. Sorry for minor issue